# Custom view with intrinsic content size in uistackview

Tags: swift, uistackview, custom-view, intrinsic-content-size

A custom view with overridden intrinsicContentSize property is added to a UIStackView

```
 override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: 100, height: 44)
  }
```

[image: Storyboard shows that the UIStackView is now missing a height property.]

Although the custom view is drawn successfully in the simulator, I still want to get rid of this storyboard error message. Thank you

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13727589/how-do-you-make-interface-builder-respect-a-custom-views-intrinsic-content-size

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are missing the constraint of the stack view not the view added to the stack. Check the constraints of the stack.

Comment: Can you please explain more about the constraint that needs to be added?

Comment: The constraint of the stackview are
`UIStackView.Leading = SafeArea.LeadingMargin`
`UIStackView.Top = SafeArea.Top`
`UIStackView.Trailing = SafeArea.TrailingMargin`

The height of UIStackView could be calculated by the arranged subview(s).

Comment: You need a constraint for the height of your stack view. Either a heigh constraint or a bottom constraint. If you want it to grow by the content you can follow https://stackoverflow.com/a/40256540/7932898